# SQL Server Management Studio error converting a string that does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, numeric

I have a table with a `varchar` column that has any kind of values. I wanted to filter only numeric values and than compare them with other Numbers. But I always get:

> Error converting varchar value "!=")" to the int-datatyp

But !=") does not even exist in there

At first I thought it might be in there and just check every requirement even if the numeric check already failed. So I put it in a sub query. But the error is still happens.

This is my query:

```
SELECT CAST(data AS float) 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Data 
     FROM [dbo].[log] 
     WHERE [Time]>='2021-08-04 00:00:00.000' 
       AND ISNUMERIC(data) = 1 
       AND Data NOT LIKE '%[^(0-9\-\.)]%'
    ) AS t
WHERE 
    data > 50
```

Any ideas?

Comment: SQL Server is under no obligation to process the clauses in the order you think; `data>50` could easily be parsed before `ISNUMERIC(data) = 1 ` or `Data NOT LIKE '%[^(0-9\-\.)]%'`. I would suggest removing those 2 clauses and just using `TRY_CONVERT(int, data) > 50`. Or, better yet, stop storing numerical data in a `varchar`

Comment: Well it is not my database, i have to work with what i get.  I assumed i would remore one of the clauses as soon i found the problem. Just tryed `TRY_CONVERT(float, data) IS NOT NULL` instead, but it resulted in the same error.

Comment: I understand that the subquery is processed in the order expected. I would bet for the `ISNUMERIC` function sometimes returns values which are not real numbers, like dots and commas. Because of you don't convert `Data`  to number in your subquery, it could give troubles in the filter `data > 50`

Comment: It is impossible for `TRY_CONVERT(float, data) IS NOT NULL`to return that error, @JaimeDrq . Presumbly you left some implicit conversions in your query still.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I made some test and you are totally right

Comment: @Lamu I tried `SELECT cast(data as float) from (SELECT DISTINCT Data FROM [dbo].[log] WHERE [Time]>='2021-08-04 00:00:00.000' AND TRY_CONVERT(float, data) IS NOT NULL) AS t WHERE data>50` and that resulted in the same error.

Comment: Because you are still implicitly converting the value, @Moeren  in your outer `WHERE`, and still using `CAST`, not `TRY_CAST` in the outer `SELECT`. See my original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755044/sql-server-management-studio-error-converting-a-string-that-does-not-exist#comment121509868_68755044) and that those clauses don't *have* to be run after the `TRY_CONVERT`. Also `TRY_CONVERT(float, '50.0')` would return `50` but `WHERE '50.0' > 50` will error as `'50.0'` can't be converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get `NULL` for invalid input data - instead of an exception. `ISNUMERIC` is notoriously bad at telling whether a column value is really numeric - or not.....

```
SELECT 
    NumericData
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         Data,
         NumericData = TRY_CAST(data AS float) 
     FROM 
         [dbo].[log] 
     WHERE 
         [Time]>='2021-08-04 00:00:00.000' 
         AND Data NOT LIKE '%[^(0-9\-\.)]%') AS t
WHERE 
    t.NumericData > 50
```

and you could find the offending data by using:

```
SELECT 
    data,
    NumericData = TRY_CAST(data AS float) 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Data 
     FROM [dbo].[log] 
     WHERE [Time]>='2021-08-04 00:00:00.000' 
       AND Data NOT LIKE '%[^(0-9\-\.)]%') AS t
WHERE 
    TRY_CAST(data AS float) IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, the query works. But offending Data query gives no results. But like i said, it is not even in the table.

Answer (score 0):

`TRY_CAST()` (or a similar function is definitely the right approach.  I want to point out that you can simplify your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRY_CAST(data AS float)  
 FROM [dbo].[log] 
 WHERE [Time] >= '2021-08-04' AND
       TRY_CAST(data AS float) > 50;
```

You do not need the time component for the time comparison.  You don't need to use `LIKE`, because `TRY_CAST()` does that for you.

Comment: Yeah the `LIKE` was just an approach to get only the numbers. One method is enough.. as long it delivers what i want.